# Find linear equation from graph (piecewise function)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to find the piecewise function in the following graph: 
[image]

From the graph I have the following intervals
\begin{equation}
G(f)=
\begin{cases}
 \begin{alignedat}{3}
&0, \quad & f&<-30M\\ 
&?, \quad & -30M\leq f &\leq -15 M\\ 
&C, \quad & -15M<f &<15M\\ 
&?, \quad & 15\leq f &\leq 30 M\\
&0, \quad & f&>30M 
\end{alignedat}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

**The straight line between $15M\leq f\leq 30M$:**

Two points: $(15M,C)$ and $(30M,0)$, the slope is 
$$
k=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}=\frac{C-0}{15M-30M}=-\frac{C}{15M}
$$
So $$G(f)=-\frac{C}{15M}f$$
But for $f=15M$ I have $G(15M)=-C$ and for $f=30M$ I have $G(30M)=-2C$?

What have I missed?

Comment: slope is not everything you need to define a linear function: $$G(f)=-\frac{C}{15M}f+2C$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 2 point form of a line ie $\,y-y_1= \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}.(x-x_1)$, where the 2 points are $\,(x_1,y_1)$ and $\,(x_2,y_2)$

So in your case ,for $15M\leq f\leq 30M$ the equation becomes : $\,G(f)-0=\frac{C-0}{15M-30M}.(f-30M)\\G(f) = \frac{-C}{15M}f+2M$